# Image segmentation using ImageJ

Tags: java, binary, 2d, image-segmentation, imagej

I'm using ImageJ and I want to implement my own function to segment a 2D binary image.
In order to do that I need to implement a region-growing function.
The first white pixel in my image is the seed indice.
Then I apply region-growing with an 4 connected neighbourhood mask.
Do you have some idea for the algorithm or an java code exemple ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [Level Sets](http://fiji.sc/Level_Sets) plugin, part of the [Fiji](http://fiji.sc/) distribution of ImageJ. I also found some [other](http://ij-plugins.sourceforge.net/plugins/segmentation/srg.html) [plugins](http://svg.dmi.unict.it/iplab/imagej/Plugins/Segmentation/Region%20Growing/Region_Growing_Segmentation.htm) with a very quick web search. What have you tried so far?

Since you are operating on binary images, see also Gabriel Landini's [Morphological Operators for ImageJ](http://www.mecourse.com/landinig/software/software.html).

Comment: I have write this code implementation [github](https://github.com/melkir/Workspace/blob/master/Image/ImageJ/src/tp6/RegionGrow.java)

Comment: @melkir Great! Are you interested in [distributing your plugin](http://imagej.net/Distribution) so that interested people can use it more easily?